# How to optimize mysql query for performance

Tags: php, mysql

I have five tables with `join`. This query takes more than 5 sec to execute. I have four queries like the one below, so my PHP page takes more than 30 sec to load. I need to improve the performance. Could you please help me? I have struggled for a week. I added indexing.

**MY QUERY**

```
SELECT f.SortField , f.id 
FROM tbl_store_brands AS sb 
INNER JOIN tbl_products AS p
    ON sb.categoryID = p.pkCategory AND sb.brandID = p.pkBrand 
INNER JOIN ModelPrice AS mp ON (p.id = mp.product_id) 
INNER JOIN Brand_Data AS bd ON bd.pkID = p.pkBrand+0 
INNER JOIN tbl_filters AS f
    ON (
        p.pkID = f.pkID and
        p.pkCategory = f.Category AND
        p.cgSlug = 'bathroom-fixtures'
    ) 
WHERE mp.Available = 1
GROUP BY f.SortField
ORDER BY if (
    f.SortField = 'CAPACITY' OR
    f.SortField = 'WIDTH' OR
    f.SortField = 'HEIGHT' OR
    f.SortField = 'DEPTH', 4, f.ValueDisplayOrder
) ASC
```

**MY Query EXPLANATION**
[image]

Comment: You don't just *"add indexing"* to magically fix a problem. You need to add specific indexes where appropriate. What indexes do you have? First thing I'd do is lose that `ORDER BY` clause. Also, why have the `GROUP BY` without any aggregation?

Comment: You can using PHP ORM, very easy to use. If you want do something like `INNER JOIN` or another, Just call your model like this (example). `TblStoreBrands::with('TblProduct')->get();`

Comment: @ArryanggaAlievPratamaputra How is that relevant?

Comment: I just giving him another solutions for that problems.

Answer (score 0):

Few modification can be done, to improve you query performance. 
1. Add index for ValueDisplayOrder, this will improve the sorting performance.
2. Avoid in query per functioning. Remove the "p.pkBrand+0", this add the execution process time. If possible remove the if clause from order by and do the ordering in your PHP code.
3. Move the "p.cgSlug = 'bathroom-fixtures'" code to on clause of product table join to narrow down the inner join result.

Your modified query will look like:

```
SELECT f.SortField , f.id 
FROM tbl_store_brands AS sb 
INNER JOIN tbl_products AS p
    ON sb.categoryID = p.pkCategory AND sb.brandID = p.pkBrand AND  p.cgSlug = 'bathroom-fixtures'
INNER JOIN ModelPrice AS mp ON (p.id = mp.product_id) 
INNER JOIN Brand_Data AS bd ON bd.pkID = p.pkBrand
INNER JOIN tbl_filters AS f
    ON (
        p.pkID = f.pkID and
        p.pkCategory = f.Category

    ) 
WHERE mp.Available = 1
GROUP BY f.SortField
ORDER BY f.ValueDisplayOrder
 ASC
```